# Chrome for Android opens new tab but remains in background when lauched from app

Tags: java, android, google-chrome

I have a app that launches Chrome. On below 6.0 all works fine, but from 6.0+ it opens a new tab with the website i want but does that on background, keeping the App on front and not switching to Chrome. Is there any code to force the Android to switch to chrome on more recent fw?

```
  String url = "googlechrome://navigate?url=www.staging.bebrightbook.com/website/?app_login="+finalstring+"&book_red="+book;
      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
    try {
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        i.setPackage(null);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: Post the relevant code snippet.

Comment: Added the relevant code

Comment: Could you please try with `url` as `"www.staging.bebrightbook.com/website/?app_login="+finalstring+"&book_red="+book;`

Comment: String url = "www.staging.bebrightbook.com/website/?app_login="+finalstring+"&book_red="+book;

Like this?

Comment: yeah like that.

Comment: That caused the app to stop working. :/

Comment: And what does the error logcat say? Could you post that?

Comment: 04-07 15:53:22.510: E/AndroidRuntime(15213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 15:53:22.510: E/AndroidRuntime(15213): Process: com.bebrightbook.bbb, PID: 15213
04-07 15:53:22.510: E/AndroidRuntime(15213): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bebrightbook.bbb/com.bebrightbook.bbb.realwebview}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.staging.bebrightbook.com/website/?app_login=joao_rueff_19@hotmail.com_123&book_red=26 flg=0x10000000 }